# Физическое движение персонажа, в сторону, в которую он смотрит в Unity 3D

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Итак, я сделал нормальное(вроде) физическое движение объекта(персонажа), но как сделать так, чтобы он шёл в сторону, в которую смотрит(Я поворачиваю игрока вместе с камерой)?
Реализация движения:
PlayerMovement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
        [SerializeField] private SurfaceSlider _surfaceSlider;
        [SerializeField] private float _speed;

    public void Move(Vector3 direction)
    {
        Vector3 directionAlongSurface = _surfaceSlider.Project(direction.normalized);
        print(transform.forward);
        Vector3 offset = directionAlongSurface * (_speed * Time.deltaTime);

        _rigidbody.MovePosition(_rigidbody.position + offset);
    }
}
```

KeyboardInput:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KeyboardInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerMovement _movement;
    [SerializeField] private FollowCamera _camera;
    private void Update()
    {
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical_cam = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        float horizontal_cam = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        _movement.Move(new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical));
        _camera.Rotate(new Vector3(-vertical_cam, horizontal_cam, 0));
    }
}
```

SurfaceSlider:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SurfaceSlider : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _normal;

    public Vector3 Project(Vector3 forward)
    {
        return forward - Vector3.Dot(forward, _normal) * _normal;
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag != "Finish")
        {
            _normal = collision.contacts[0].normal;
        } 
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.black;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + _normal * 3);
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + Project(transform.forward));
    }
}
```

Comment: Точно так же, как ты и это сделал. Загуглить туториал и сделать то, что делают там.

Comment: Прикол в том, что объект поворачивается, камера поворачивается, но он не двигается в ту сторону которую смотрит, он всё также двигается по оси x, когда я жму "W", Я хотел чтобы это было так:
Я иду вперёд, повернул камеру(а с ней и персонаж) направо, и теперь он идёт вправо.

Comment: В том то и прикол, что он идёт не туда куда смотрит камера(и игрок), а по оси x.

Comment: Ну да, ты же двигаешь его только по х и z, не учитывая направления камеры. `unity движение относительно камеры` вот тебе запрос в гугл.

Comment: О, действительно нашёл, до этого делал не совсем корректные запросы, спасибо.

Comment: Я новичок, и пока только учусь по туторам Скаутина и ITproger'a, посоветуешь может какие-то курсы где поменьше воды? Пока что мне больше нравятся туторы и курсы ITProger'a, но там много воды.

Comment: [От юнити курсы](https://learn.unity.com/). На русском не знаю, можешь купить/скачать с торрента курс Сакутина, там, судя по отзывам, воды меньше. По c# - [Ulearn](https://ulearn.me/)